# How to append time part of DateTime literal to a DateTime variable?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, append, literals

My project is of .net 3.5.
I have a DateTime variable `dt1` containing only Date part, now I want to append time part of DateTime literal `# 13:45:39 #` to `dt1` and assign to a new DateTime variable `dt2`. Anyone know how to do?

```
DateTime dt1 = #2016/12/31# ;
DateTime dt2 = /*code to append # 13:45:39 # to dt1 */  ;
```

Comment: Is `# 13:45:39 #` a string or `TimeSpan`?

Comment: `# 13:45:39 #` is DateTime literal

Comment: There is no `DateTime` literal in C# (as opposed to VB.NET)

Comment: Re: `Tim Schmelter` why? Is `# 2016/04/28 #` a literal of DataTime?

Comment: Yes, but only in VB.NET. In C# there is no `DateTime` literal. In VB.NET you can declare a `DateTime` variable in this way: `Dim dt = # 2016/04/28 #`. That doesn't work or compile in C#.

Comment: I see, thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My project is of .net 3.5. I have a DateTime variable dt1 containing
>   only Date part

[`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime) is a `struct` in .NET Framework. It *always* has date and time parts. By this sentence, I *assume* your time part is `00:00:00` like;

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2016, 12, 31);
```

> I want to append time part of DateTime literal # 13:45:39 # to dt1 and
>   assign to a new DateTime variable dt2

It is not clear what this *literal* means in that sentence but if you have a [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan) as `13:45:39`, you can clearly add this value to your `dt1` with [`DateTime.Add(TimeSpan)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add) method like;

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(13, 45, 39);
dt1 = dt1.Add(ts);
```

If this `# 13:45:39 #` is a string, you can parse it to `TimeSpan` with [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parseexact) method first then use this `Add` method again like;

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact("# 13:45:39 #", "'# 'hh\\:mm\\:ss' #'", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dt1 = dt1.Add(ts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(dt1.Year, dt1.Month, dt1.Day, 13, 45, 39);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `DateTime literal # 13:45:39 #` means that you have one DatetIme for the date and one for the time, you can use `DateTIme.Add` and `DateTime.TimeOfDay` to get the timespan:

```
DateTime dtDate = new DateTime(2016, 12, 31);
DateTime dtTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 13, 45, 39);
DateTime result = dtDate.Date.Add(dtTime.TimeOfDay);
```

If the mentioned time literal is actually a string use `TimeSpan.Parse`/`TryParse`:

```
string timeString = "# 13:45:39 #";
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse(timeString.Trim(' ', '#'));
result = dtDate.Date.Add(time);
```